# Problems with outer function

Tags: performance, r

I'm pretty new in using R. I'm trying to use `dcor` (distance correlation) on row pairs of a matrix by `outer` function. My code works for small test matrix (100x100) but I tried to apply it on the real one (5000 x 700), and it is taking more than a week without giving me a result. Is it normal?
Any advice to get a result in a faster way?

the code is:

```
library(energy)
outer (1:n, 1:n, FUN=Vectorize (function (i,j) dcor (a[i,], a[j,])))
```

`n` is the number of rows of the matrix.

Comment: What kind of object is `a`? Do you have sufficient physical RAM?

Comment: yes, my RAM is enough. "a" is the matrix from which I need to take the row pairs.

Comment: Which package is `dcor` in?

Comment: it is in the "energy" package that require "boot" and "MASS" also.

Comment: By using `outer` you are doing redundant calculations, since the upper and lower triangular part of the result are the same. You should calculate unique combinations of row numbers and only loop through those. Furthermore, you can optimize `dcor`. The function does a lot of calculations, which are redundant in your loop (eg., `nrow(x)`).

Comment: your real example is 350 times bigger than your test example.  How long does your test example take?  If it's approximately (`7*24/350`) a half hour, then all you're seeing here is linear scaling. @Roland's point is correct, but doing both halves of the matrix accounts for "only" a doubling of the time.

Comment: my example test takes about 20 sec.

Comment: may be combn can work to create unique row combinations?

Comment: or just loop (or `*apply`) over dependent indices: `for (i in 1:N) {for (j in 1:i) {your dcoR work here} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the math: `dcor(X, Y)` does

1. compute something expensive on `X` alone (those `A_kl`) and `Y` alone (those `B_kl`)
2. do something inexpensive with the results of 1) and 2)

When you are calling `dcor` with every combination (pair) of rows from your data, the first expensive step is called over and over: for each row, the same `A_kn` is computed a total of `2*n` times (or `n` times if you used a smarter double loop as suggested.) although you really need it to compute it once.

Conclusion: you'll be *way* better off writing your own algorithm:

1. for each row of your data, compute `A_kl`
2. write a function that does the last step of the `dcor` function: take `A_kl` and `B_kl` as inputs and returns the distance correlation,
3. call that function through `outer` or a double loop as suggested.

Note that each `A_kn` is a matrix of dimension 700-by-700 and you would have 5000 of them, so you might have to opt for a suboptimal algorithm that strikes a balance between speed and memory usage.